# Add Red dot to a tab bar ios

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

i would like to add a little red dot with a number to a tab bar icon. 
It would look like for example the red dot of your sms icon saying that you have 3 unread messages

any idea how to do it ?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[self tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"YourBadgeValue"; //3, in your case
```